# JSF Primefaces multi level Dynamic menu from database

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, menu

I am generating a menubar from database table, i am able to generate the first level submenus but i am not able to get submenus childs(items).
I can't find the logic to generate the childs on primefaces.
Here's the sql result of my query.Can anyone help for getting the solution?

[image]

Here is my code for first level generation

```
//get menu options from database
ResultSet result =  ps.executeQuery();
        int parent=0; 
        DefaultSubMenu firstSubmenu = null;
 while(result.next()){
     int parent_id=result.getInt("parent_option_id");
     int suboption_id=result.getInt("sub_option_id");
     int subopt_nb=result.getInt("totalSubopt");

     if (result.getInt("parent_option_id")==0)
      {
      firstSubmenu = new DefaultSubMenu(result.getString("name"));


         DefaultMenuItem item = new              DefaultMenuItem(result.getString("name"));
         firstSubmenu.setStyleClass("parent"+suboption_id);
         firstSubmenu.setId("parent"+Integer.toString(suboption_id));
        item.setUrl(result.getString("url"));
        item.setIcon("ui-icon-home");

        firstSubmenu.addElement(item);

         menu.addElement(firstSubmenu);
       } 
   }
```

Another thing that is disturbing me, the setId is not working i tried many examples and it's not rendering ??

Answer (score 1):

First of all

1. Write a db query that returns the Parent's list (select * where parent_option_id is not null)
2. Iterate the list of parents and for for each parent get the list of children ( select * where parent_option_id = ?)

Here is the code to create the menu and sub menu items

```
MenuModel menuModel = new DefaultMenuModel();
```

for parent_option_Id 1

```
DefaultSubMenu menu = new DefaultSubMenu(getParentName());
menu.setLabel("name");
```

for each subItems of parent_option_id 1

```
DefaultMenuItem resources = new DefaultMenuItem(getSubItemName());
resources.setUrl("subItemUrl");
menu.addElement(resources);
```

At the end of subItems list (after closing for loop)
    menuModel.addElement(menu);

Comment: Ok that's for 2 levels menu, but here I have a 3 level menu, do you have an idea how to make a condition that makes a default submenu if it has a child and an item if not

Comment: Ok thanks I started from your logic and I have done it, but in our case we are limited by knowing the number of levels, what if one day we have to add a new level, we will be in the obligation of adding a new while loop whith a new query.

Comment: learn recursive programming. Works great in situations like this